# Lumen: redirect() not work

Tags: laravel, redirect, lumen

I have a problem with redirection in Lumen framework. My code is

```
$del = Fees::find($id)->delete();

if($del) {
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

when I execute this code by route then server response 500 Server Internal error and redirection not work. Where the problem. What can I do?

Comment: Would you mind to post your error log?

Comment: There are no error display on screen. a blank page are display.

Comment: You can find it in `storage/logs/lumen.log`.

Comment: And your data already deleted in your database?

Comment: Yes, my data already deleted but redirection not work :(

Comment: You may change your application configuration to display exception stack trace by set debug to true in your .env file. Then update your question by posting your error stack trace. It's very difficult to me to figure out the cause of your error.

Comment: Thank you all to quick response. I already solve this problem. This is Cache driver issue.